# PHP Form echoing Post variable not working

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
ob_start();
// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
define('MyConst', TRUE);

include('../database.class.php');
include('../table.class.php'); 
include('../user.class.php');
include('../loginattempts.class.php');
include('../timer.class.php');
include('../characters.class.php');
include('../weapontype.class.php');
include('../objects/weapons/weaponobject.class.php');
include('../objects/weapons/bowieknife.class.php');
include('../npc/enemy.class.php');
include('../npc/skinhead.class.php');
include('../npc.class.php');
include('../npctype.class.php');
include('../functions.php');
include('../loginf.php');  
include('locationf.php');

$dbo = database::getInstance();
$dbo -> connect("***************", "********", "********", "***************", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8')); 

secSessionStart();

// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
    header("Location: login.php"); 

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
}

$_SESSION['currentlocation'] = "combat.php";
?>
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
{
$varMovie = $_POST['formMovie'];

 echo $varMovie;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>


<form action="index.php" method="post">

Which is your favorite movie?
<input type="text" name="formMovie" maxlength="50">

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ok...so its supposed to echo out some text. Instead it just reloads the form! I'm not sure what else to write and it won't allow me to post so i'm just going to repeat what i've wrote until i reach the limit.

Comment: a) Make sure you have the method="POST" in your form.
b) If it is POST, then add var_dump($_POST) to the top of the script to see what's getting sent

Comment: Do you have `$_SESSION['user']` set? @jraede please read his code, he has that already :)

Comment: "so i'm just going to repeat what i've wrote until i reach the limit." -Insanity

Comment: Don't mix HTML and PHP together; it's so messy.

Comment: Yeah, too much code to sift through. So please add var_dump($_POST); to the top and we'll go from there.

Comment: @jraede i did var_dump. apparently its just sending an empty array.

Comment: @tftd yes. $_SESSION['user'] is set.

Comment: try removing `name="formSubmit"` in this line `<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">`. I'm not sure but I think you shouldn't have that there.

Comment: @user2361103 Regarding "I'm not sure what else to write...", we might benefit from knowing what you've tried already, and what your dev environment is like; Apache/IIS, MySQL, and/or PHP versions tend to be useful...

Comment: @tftd Then `if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")` could never result true.

Comment: If there's nothing in the $_POST variable then you have something wrong with your server environment

Answer (score 0):

Add an ELSE part in the HTML, that will either show the form OR the answer, but keeps the header etc intact.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>

<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
{
$varMovie = $_POST['formMovie'];

 echo $varMovie;
}
else {
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">

Which is your favorite movie?
<input type="text" name="formMovie" maxlength="50">

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">

</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this help? The problem is it's not echoing anything out.

Comment: It helps because it seem to be a problem for the OP that the form redisplays. Also the postdata was displayed without any HTML headers, which normally works but could cause problems...

Comment: this answer is correct. he prolly is to lazy to test the code. if you output $_POST['formMovie'] before you output your <html> then its normal that there is nothing in the post. an alternative is to append exit(); or die(); right after echo $varMovie;

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to use:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists("formSubmit",$_POST) && !strcmp($_POST["formSubmit"],'Submit'))
{
  $varMovie = $_POST['formMovie'];

  echo "Movie=(${varMovie})<br>\n";
}
:
:
```

Also comment out all the includes etc. above this, check it's giving you the contents of formMovie then add the other stuff back in gradually until it fails (or not).
Cheers.